# Truth Tables (Kotlin Android Studio)

Tags: android, kotlin

It's like this for the first time here, I'm learning to use the programming language Kotlin, I have to develop a Boolean formula with true or false, I already do it in Java and it was like that, in java

```
public class xdddd {

private static final boolean VALUES[] = new boolean[]{true,false};
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.println("a\t\tb\t\tc\t\td\t\t(avb)\t(c^d)\t(avb) ->  (c^d)\t 'xor'(avb) -> !(cvd) \t !(avb) != (a=b) -> !(cvd)\r\n" + 
            "");
    for( boolean a : VALUES )               
    {
        for( boolean b: VALUES )
        {
            for( boolean c: VALUES )
            {
                for( boolean d: VALUES )
                {
                    for( boolean e: VALUES )
                    {
                        for( boolean f: VALUES )
                        {
                            System.out.println(a+"\t"+"\t"+b+"\t"+"\t"+c+"\t"+"\t"+d+"\t"+"\t"+or(a,b)+"\t"+and(c,d)+"\t\t"
                                    +conditional(or(a,b),and(c,d))+"\t"+"\t"+xor(e,f)+"\t"+"\t"+disequal(or(a,b),xor(e,f)));

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public static boolean or( boolean x , boolean y )
{
    return x || y;
}
public static boolean and( boolean x , boolean y )
{
    return x && y;
}
public static boolean xor( boolean x , boolean y )
{
    return x ^ y;
}
public static boolean conditional( boolean x , boolean y )
{
    return !(x && y);

}
public static boolean bicontional( boolean x , boolean y )
{
    return x == y;
}   

public static boolean disequal ( boolean x , boolean y )
{
    return x != y;
}
```

I want to do it now in Kotlin, to show it all in textview without the need to use String and compare the Booleans to create the own formula

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val textview:TextView = findViewById(R.id.textview) as TextView



    val a = true;
    val b = false;



    val a1 = a && a
    val a2 = a && b
    val a3 = b && a
    val a4 = b && b


    val b1 = a || a
    val b2 = a || b
    val b3 = b || a
    val b4 = b || b


    val c1 = a xor a
    val c2 = a xor b
    val c3 = b xor a
    val c4 = b xor b

    val d1 = !a and b
    val d2 = a and !b


    val myString0 = "Tabla de AND \n";
        val myString2 = "$a  y $a = $a1 \n";
        val myString3 =  "$a  y $b = $a2 \n";
        val myString4 =  "$b  y $a = $a3 \n";
        val myString5=  "$b  y $b = $a4 \n";


    val myString6 = "\n";
    val myString7 = "Tabla de OR \n";

    val myString8 = "$a  y $a = $b1 \n";
    val myString9 =  "$a  y $b = $b2 \n";
    val myString10 =  "$b  y $a = $b3 \n";
    val myString11 =  "$b  y $b = $b4 \n";

    val myString12 = "\n";
    val myString13 = "Tabla de XOR \n";

    val myString14 = "$a  y $a = $c1 \n";
    val myString15 =  "$a  y $b = $c2 \n";
    val myString16 =  "$b  y $a = $c3 \n";
    val myString17 =  "$b  y $b = $c4 \n";



    val myString18 = "\n";
    val myString19 = "Tabla de NOT \n";

    val myString20 =  "$a  y $b = $d1 \n";
    val myString21 =  "$a  y $b = $d2 \n";




    textview.setText( myString0 + myString2 + myString3 + myString4 + myString5 +  myString6 + myString7 + myString8 + myString9 + myString10 + myString11 +myString12 +myString13 + myString14 + myString15
     + myString16 + myString17 + myString18 + myString19 + myString20 + myString21)

    textview.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod())
```

What function could I use to compare Booleans and be able to represent it in the Android textview?

Thanks

Comment: Operators in Kotlin are exactly the same as in Java. What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: I want to compare booleans added and kotlin does not allow me, what can I do?

Comment: It's not that Kotlin is not allowing you to. Your syntax is just off a bit. I added explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.example.user.herramientaslogica

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import org.w3c.dom.Text
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val VALUES = booleanArrayOf(true, false)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val textview:TextView = findViewById(R.id.textview) as TextView

        for (a in VALUES)

        {
            for (b in VALUES)
            {
                for (c in VALUES)
                    for (d in VALUES)
                    {
                        for (e in VALUES)
                        {
                            for (f in VALUES)
                            {
                                textview.setText(booleanArrayOf(a + b + c + d + d + e + f )
                                )
     textview.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod())
    }

                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
fun or(x:Boolean, y:Boolean):Boolean {
    return x || y
}
fun and(x:Boolean, y:Boolean):Boolean {
    return x && y
}
fun xor(x:Boolean, y:Boolean):Boolean {
    return x xor y
}
fun conditional(x:Boolean, y:Boolean):Boolean {
    return !(x && y)
}
fun bicontional(x:Boolean, y:Boolean):Boolean {
    return x == y
}
fun disequal(x:Boolean, y:Boolean):Boolean {
    return x != y
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin doesn't allow `+` to be on the next line.

This will work though:

```
textview.setText( myString0 + myString2 + myString3 + myString4 + myString5 +  
 myString6 + myString7 + myString8 + myString9 + myString10 + myString11 +myString12 +
 myString13 + myString14 + myString15 + myString16 + myString17 + myString18 + 
 myString19 + myString20 + myString21)
```

This is even better:

```
textview.setText("""$myString0 $myString2 $myString3 $myString4 $myString5 $myString6 $myString7 $myString8
        | $myString9 $myString10 $myString11 $myString12 $myString13 $myString14 $myString15 $myString16""".trimMargin())
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try how it works, thank you for your interest

Comment: I have already changed it, how can I make the following formula in kotlin to be able to generate these tables similar to the first and compare booleans
Please? https://mathpullzone-8231.kxcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/truth-table-example1-compound3.png

Comment: This is not a formula, but a table. And it's not really related to your question. But the principle is the same. Loop 8 times (2^3), map index to bits, then print results using string evaluation.

Comment: I have finished now the problem is to show the booleans in the textview